# Part of a proof for Wilson's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking at [this proof](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/Wilsons.html) of Wilson's Theorem, and it uses a fact that for a prime $p$ and $a,a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$, $$a = a^{-1} \text{ if and only if } a = 1,p-1.$$

For the $\Leftarrow$ direction, it's easy to see, just a straight computation ($1^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$ and $(p-1)^2 = p^2 -2p + 1 \equiv 1 \mod p$), but I am not sure how the $\Rightarrow$ direction works. Could someone explain how this direction works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $r^2=1 \operatorname{mod} p$, then $r^2-1=(r-1)(r+1)=0 \operatorname{mod} p$. Now use the fact that $p$ is prime and conclude the desired result.